How can I use OkHttp pinging as heart-beating of STOMP protocol?
I need to implement an Android client part of STOMP protocol and I use OkHttp and its web-socket features for this. I also need to implement heart-beating. I wonder if using pings by setting .pingInterval() in OkHttpClient can be used as heart-beating in STOMP protocol or it can't?
Or may be it can be used as heart-beating if server implements this protocol based on web-sockets too?

STOMP and HTTP are independent protocols. Pings for HTTP are not the same as STOMP heart-beats.
